# Implement content-nosidebar.php / content-leftsidebar.php

Tags: theme-development, page-template

I've been trying to create Page Layout's so that the person using the theme to position the sidebar either on the left, right or have the page as a full width one. I've looked at another theme and they have files called content-nosidebar.php and so on for left and right so I've gone a head and done that but something tells me I need to call some kind of function for this.

I've looked around the WordPress codex but that says something about Page Templates and like I said I'm fairly new to it so if you could help me by pointing me in the right direction that would be awesome  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your functions.php

```
    if( !function_exists( 'my_custom_widgetize_theme' ) ){

        add_action ( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_custom_widgetize_theme', 10 );

        function my_custom_widgetize_theme(){

            register_sidebar(array(
                'name' => 'My SideBar',
                'id'   => 'my_sidebar',
                'description'   => 'This is the widgetized Side Bar.',
                'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget'  => '</div>',
                'before_title'  => '<h4>',
                'after_title'   => '</h4>'
            ));

        }

}

//this will be display your side bar

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
     <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('private_event')); ?>
</div>
```

after you add this code, you'll see your new sidebar on your  dashboard widgets area, there you can drop your menus etc.. wordpress

Comment: Okay I've just realized I've already done this in my code -  http://prntscr.com/9hkudx - but when I go to edit a page it doesn't give me the Page Layout option where I can have a full width page or a sidebar page

Comment: i think you need to creat defrnt tamplate for that..

Comment: <?php
/**
 *  Template Name: Register
 *
?>

add this line in top of your new tamplatename-page.php

Comment: please check this link http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: Please add an **explanation** to your answer.